# Iterating a function over a nested list of dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, nested-lists

I am having a hard time iterating a function over a list of dataframes, I would like to create another list dataframes appying the repr() function over each element in a specific column of every dataframe in a nested list in order to get a sense of the elemnts that have hidden control characters. I have a list of dataframes like this:

`df_list = [df1, df2, df3]`

And every dataframe in the list looks like this:

```
    df1:                     df2:                     df3:
    ID    REG                ID    REG                ID    REG
    aad   03158              aee   05268              sse   05214
    eed   02545              fed   09679              fbh   02684
    xxe   01256              hyd   04784              ghu   03689
```

So I am trying to use the repr() function in a loop in order to get the following result:

`df_list2 = [df4, df5, df6]`

Where every resulting dataframe should be:

```
    df4:               df5:             df6:
    REG                REG              REG
    03158\r\r\n        05268            05214\r\r\n
    02545\r\r\n        09679            02684
    01256              04784\r\r\n      03689\r\r\n
```

I tried using a loop like this:

```
    df_list2 = []

    for datafr in df_list:
        for element in datafr[]:
            df_list2[].append(repr(elemnt))
```

And I got a flat list instead:

`df_list2 = ['03158\r\r\n', '05268', '05214\r\r\n', '02545\r\r\n', '09679', '02684', '01256', '04784\r\r\n', '03689\r\r\n']`

Any hints about how I can fix this?, I read many other answers about the topic but I couldn't get any idea on how to approach the problem, I am a begginer in Python so I thought I would be a good idea to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply() for each dataframe in df_list

```
df_list2 = []

for datafr in df_list:
    df_list2.append(pd.DataFrame({'REG': datafr['REG'].apply(repr)}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer worked perfectly, (I edited the question and I corrected some grammar and other minor typing errors)